# Is the co-slice category of a pre-topos a pre-topos?

Tags: category-theory

A pre-topos $\mathbb{C}$ is a category which is exact and extensive (it is in particular a coherent category, [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pretopos)). Let $X$ be an object of $\mathbb{C}$, and write $\mathbb{C}^{X/}$ for the co-slice category (under-category) of morphisms $X\to A$, $A\in \mathbb{C}$. Is $\mathbb{C}^{X/}$ a pre-topos?

Answer (score 1):

No; here's why: pretoposes always have coproducts; in the co-slice pretopos, coproducts are pushouts in the original pretopos. Pushouts generalize coequalizers, and pretoposes do not generally have coequalizers.

Comment: I would just like to provide an example because that was what I was looking for and it seems to be given nowhere even if it's not hard: take the theory of simple graphs (symmetric reflexive relations). Then the transitive closure of the relation is not definable, so the classifying pretopos doesn't have coequalizers. (A pretopos has coequalizers iff each relation has a transitive symmetric reflexive closure in it.)